# Select from mysql using a counter mixing up the results

Tags: mysql

i want to select products from a table.
The data will be sorted based on product_rank
But each 3 or 5 products i want to select another product from the same table with highbidder (CPC) even if the ranking is not good enough!
Let´s say the table has only 4 fields:

```
ID         Title          Rank          CPC
```

Has someone an idea how to achive that with a couter where i define every how much products it should show how many products of highbidder?

thanks for help

Edit:
here are some sample data

```
1        shoes A        500    0.4
2        shoes B        0      0.9
3        shoes C        480    0.5
4        shoes D        600    0.3
5        shoes E        550    0.4
6        shoes F        300    0.5
7        shoes G        80     0.8
8        shoes H        800    0.35
9        shoes I        100    0.8
10       shoes J        900    0.4
```

Let´s say i want to show at every third position the high bidder. The excepted result is the following

```
shoes J (best rank)
shoes H (2nd best rank)
shoes B (1st highbidder)
shoes D (3rd best rank)
shoes E (4th best rank)
shoes I (2nd highbidder and better rank than G!!)
```

etc...

It should be only one select statement if possible.
thank you

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

could be used to tell it that you selected 5 of them previously and want the next 10, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

to do that specific of ordering is not easy at all... this took a bit of fiddling around with but will do what you want.. it is ordered by 2 rank then 1 cpc by greatest rank and cpc.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    (SELECT 
        id, title, rank AS my_rank, count_col
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            id, title, rank, @C:=@C + 1 AS testing,
            IF(@C MOD 3 = 0, @C:=@C + 1, @C) AS count_col
        FROM
            products
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @C:=0) t
        ORDER BY rank DESC) AS temprank) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT 
        id, title, cpc AS my_rank, count_col
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            id, title, cpc, @B:=@B + 3 AS count_col
        FROM
            products
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @B:=0) t
        ORDER BY cpc DESC) tempcpc) 
    ORDER BY count_col
    ) as total_rows
group by id
order by count_col
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c2bb/1)

sample output. http://screencast.com/t/uMSPU9IiEyg6

Comment: thanks but it didn´t work for me. I am not just fiddling around ;-)
if you look at the ebay website and make a search eg. 'Jeans' you will see that every second or third product is an auction. It is basically the same they want to show auction i want to show at those positions the high bidder. Just mixing up the results!

Comment: @ahajji06 not sure how this is not working.. let me post a sql fiddle with the output. it orders it in that order. do you want to show all of the results? aka show the shoes A twice once for the cpc and once for the rank? or just show it once?

Comment: @ahajji06 i just added the sql fiddle to my answer under DEMO... i never said you were fiddling around I said it `took a bit of fiddling around with` meaning it took some work and tweaks to get it working.